# spring/application-config.xml cannot be opened because it does not exist ..with Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

i was trying to deploy my war (Spring boot) on tomcat  but some how i am getting this exception. I have tried another questions on stackoverflow before asking my own,unfortunately they dont help much.

Its looking for Application-config.xml and in Spring boot we dont have xml configuration files at all.

I am creating war using Maven.

Any pointers would be helpful.

**Exception**

> localhost.2015-09-04.log <== 04-Sep-2015 11:50:40.856 SEVERE
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-40]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception
>   sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from class path resource
>   [spring/application-config.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [spring/application-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not
>   exist
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1293)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:673)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:221)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)

My **pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- This dependency is used ,so that embedded server is not part of war -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Let me know if more information is required from my side.since i am not sure what all is required to explain my problem . i have just provided Exception and pom.

Thanks

Comment: Well the error is pretty clear, the file isn't there... Make sure the file is in the location you specified.

Comment: M.Deinum : ofcourse its self explainatory but  in spring boot ..xml's are not used. :)

Comment: Well you deploying to tomcat, so you are probably have something in your file that is basically ignoring Spring Boot. I suspect you added a web.xml which contains a `COntextLoaderListener` with some configuration. Which is basically working against spring boot.

Comment: M.Deinum i have double checked i dont have any xml file. Do we need anything special to deploy Spring boot war ? . Other than that i dont have any xml file in project.

Comment: You need a class that extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` if you have written your own `WebApplicationInitializer` which registers `ContextLoaderListener` (instead of the web.xml) then it won't work. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Comment: Search on your source code for this String "application-config.xml"! Does it referenced on any Class(annotation...)

Comment: @Guissouma Issam i have just tried to search *.xml but  i have not found anything.

Comment: Is it possible that something is missing or extra in Pom.xml?

Comment: @Roxy Try to search in files contents, not an xml file.

Comment: @GUISSOUMAIssam i did that , but no there is not any.

Comment: @Roxy Have you tried performing a maven clean and then rebuilding the war?

Comment: @geoand ... well it sounds stupid, but yes cleaning and building ...worked for me. thank :)

Comment: @Roxy It's not the first time I've come across an issue being fixed by cleaning :P

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the xml file exists. Maven `Clean & Compile` resolved the issue.